# Google Apps Script - When a new data containing row is added to Sheet 1, move that to a new row in Sheet 2, then clear the data from Sheet 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- Row 1 in both Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are frozen, with column names.
- Once I have a working script, I will setup a corresponding onChange trigger to execute the script.
- Due to the way new data containing rows are added to Sheet 1, the script itself cannot be written with onChange/onEdit syntax, I just need a function that works, and I'll use an onChange trigger to execute it.

**Step 1:**

Sheet 1 - a new data containing row was added (Row 2).

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | Los Angeles | CA | USA |

Sheet 2 - the data from Sheet 1 - Row 2 should be copied to the next available row, which in this case would be Row 2.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | Los Angeles | CA | USA |

**Step 2:**

Sheet 1 - after the data from Row 2 has been copied to the next available row in Sheet 2, then Row 2 should be cleared.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | blank | blank | blank |

**Step 3:**

Sheet 1 - a new data containing row was added (Row 2).

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | Miami | FL | USA |

Sheet 2 - the data from Sheet 1 - Row 2 should be copied to the next available row, which in this case would be Row 3.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | Los Angeles | CA | USA |
| 3 | Miami | FL | USA |

**Step 4:**

Sheet 1 - after the data from Row 2 has been copied to the next available row in Sheet 2, then Row 2 should be cleared.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **City** | **State** | **Country** |
| 2 | blank | blank | blank |

**...and so on**

- Sheet 1 should only ever have two rows. Row 1 for the column names and Row 2, which will be blank to start, then filled with data (which should then be copied over to Sheet 2), then cleared so that it is blank again, repeat.
- Sheet 2's row count should be continually growing, one by one, as individual data containing rows populate into Sheet 1 - Row 2 over time and get copied over.
- The incoming data that fills Sheet 1 - Row 2 comes from an external app, I'm never manually entering data into that sheet/row. The incoming data fills all columns in Sheet 1 - Row 2, all at once.

Comment: `Due to the way new data containing rows are added to Sheet 1` ... how do you add this new row? by a google form? manually in Sheet1? First case, you will need onFormSubmit trigger, Second case you can play with onEdit incolumn#3 (the last one that is introduced)

Comment: From an external app, never manually. The incoming data will fill all columns in Sheet 1 - Row 2, all at once. Then I just want a script that will copy that data over to the next available row in Sheet 2, then clear the data from Sheet 1 - Row 2. I can deal with / setup the trigger, I just need a script that even if I manually run it, would just grab whatever's in Sheet 1 - Row 2, copy it to the next available row in Sheet 2, then clear Sheet 1 - Row 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Transfer data form Sheet1 to Sheet2', 'moveData')
    .addToUi();
}
function moveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var rng = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A2:C2')
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getLastRow()+1,1,1,3).setValues(rng.getValues())
  rng.clearContent()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, you rock man, works like a charm :) Didn't need the onOpen function, but nice to see how that works (adding a UI feature). I used the moveData function in tandem with an onChange trigger, and it works flawlessly. Thanks :)